# TFS: Is it possible to do a merge after source move during previous merge?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, tfs, merge

In TFS2010 we have:

- created a new project X in branch A at path $\TeamProject\A\Path1
- We have merged this into branch B and within the merge we also moved the project to path  $\TeamProject\B\Path2 (this change has type "merge, branch") in the same check-in.
- made some change to branch A.

Now I want to merge the change to branch B, but instead of "merge, edit" files in path $\TeamProject\B\Path2, I got "merge, branch" on $\TeamProject\B\Path1.

For each file in branch B I can see the history in branch A on the old path.

What am I doing wrong (except doing the move action inside merge)?

It seem to be allowed but not supported action.

Is it possible to do the merge now somehow?

Answer (score 2):

This is just not supported in UI.

command

```
 tf merge /recursive $\TeamProject\A\Path1 C:\TeamProject\B\Path2 /version:{changesetnumber}
```

in console did the requested work...